# 2>&1 | tee cannot get full output log

Tags: tee, timeout

I'm using the timeout command to call my application in timeout duration. And I also use `2>&1 | tee` to write the log in my application to a `log.txt` file.

The command: `timeout 20 my_application 2>&1 | tee log.txt`

But when the timeout happens, I cannot see the full log in the terminal and in `log.txt` also.

Then I tried to call only: `timeout 20 my_application` (*without `2>&1 | tee.log`*), and I can see the full log from `my_application` on the terminal.

Can you help explain why this happens, and how can I fix it?
Thanks so much

Comment: Is `my_application` written to do something different with its log messages depending on whether or not it's writing to a terminal?

Comment: @roaima, actually, I didn't get your question clearly. But, my_application is the qt app, and it uses the qt log mechanism to write the output log.

Comment: Perhaps your application is logging lines in a different way. If you test with a simple script it shouldn't happen. Perhaps you could experiment with the `-s` option of timeout to send a different signal.

Comment: Indeed, does `timeout --signal SIGHUP 20 my_application 2>&1 | tee log.txt` work better for you?

Comment: It still happens @roaima if I specify SIGHUP signal, the my_application only shows a full log if I don't use 2>&1 | tee. I use another solution is calling "timeout 20 my_application > log.txt" to get full log, but if that I cannot see the output stream on the terminal.

Comment: That's useful to know. Please would you add it to your question so it's easy for everyone to find

Comment: Also, probably you need to add more details for the application and how you run it. Currently I see in comments it is a Qt application.